# Approach to Redis transactions with "rollback"

Tags: error-handling, transactions, redis, server, rollback

I am currently implementing a server system which has both an SQL database and a Redis datastore. The data written to Redis heavily depends on the SQL data (cache, objects representing logic entities defined by a number of SQL models and their relationships).

While looking for an error handling methodology to wrap client requests, something similar to SQL's transaction commit & rollback (Redis doesn't support rollbacks), I thought of a mechanism which can serve this purpose and **I'd appreciate input** regarding it.

Basically, I intend to wrap (with before/after middleware) every client request with an SQL transaction and a Redis `multi` command (pipes commands until `exec` or `discard` command is invoked), and allow both transactions to occur only if the request was processed successfully.

The problem is that once you start a Redis `multi` command, you are not able to preform any reads/writes and actually use their values while processing a request. I reduced the problem just for reads since depending on just-now written values can be optimized out.

My (simple) solution: split the Redis connection into two - a writer and a reader. The writer connection will be the one to be initialized with the `multi` command and executed/discarded at the end. Of course, all writing will be preformed through it, while reading is done using the reader (executed instantly).

- The down side: as opposed to SQL, you can't rely on values written in the same request (transaction). Then again, usually quite easy to overcome.

Comment: S.M, have a similar scenario. are you doing the the above way or any changes?

Comment: @ravishanker, although the way I described actually DID work, in order to simplify things I ended up still wrapping the API call with an SQL transaction, reads to Redis are done arbitrarily and I wrote a mechanism that holds the commands to run on Redis for write purposes and only on successful commit to SQL I call to execute these commands.

Comment: Might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585903/how-to-implement-transaction-with-rollback-in-redis/76807035#76807035