# Wrapping a redis transaction inside a database transaction

Tags: ruby, postgresql, redis

I'm trying to pull a bunch of records stored in a redis queue and write them to the database in batches of 1000.

The idea is to wrap a redis transaction inside a database transaction so in case the db commit fails the redis transaction would explode too so the elements I `lpop`'ed wouldn't disappear, here's a simple example for 10 records:

```
  REDIS.with do |redis|
    redis.multi do |multi|
      MyRailsModel.transaction do
        10.times do
          attrs = JSON.parse(multi.lpop("foo"))
          MyRailsModel.create(attrs)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

The example uses `ActiveRecord` conventions, but would work with any setup.

Problem I get is that `multi.lpop("foo")` doesn't really return a value but a `Redis::Future` - and if I try to simply put `SON.parse(multi.lpop("foo").value)` I get a `Redis::FutureNotReady: Value will be available once the pipeline executes.` error.

I'm starting to get the feeling from Redis apis that what I'm trying to do may not be feasible, but I find it hard to believe something so basic such as getting a value is not possible in a Redis transaction, so I'm hoping someone knows something I'm missing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement transaction with rollback in Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585903/how-to-implement-transaction-with-rollback-in-redis)

Comment: Might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585903/how-to-implement-transaction-with-rollback-in-redis/76807035#76807035

Answer (score 4):

Transactions in Redis are very different things from transactions in Postgres. From the [Redis docs](https://redis.io/topics/transactions#usage):

> A Redis transaction is entered using the `MULTI` command. The command always replies with `OK`. At this point the user can issue multiple commands. Instead of executing these commands, Redis will queue them. All the commands are executed once `EXEC` is called.

So nothing actually happens in a Redis transaction until you `EXEC`, at which point it runs everything at once, with no way for you to intervene in between commands.

And these are not [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) transactions; they provide [isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)), but not [atomicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)). There is no way to roll back a change, and to make matters worse:

> **even when a command fails, all the other commands in the queue are processed** – Redis will *not* stop the processing of commands.

(Of course, there's a good reason for all of this: Redis is single-threaded, so commands are isolated simply because they never run in parallel, and a "transaction" is nothing more than a guarantee that your block of commands won't be interleaved with anyone else's. And of course, it wants to execute that block as fast as physically possible, and it's not going to waste its time waiting on round-trips back to your client, or versioning all of your data to cater for the occasional rollback.)

---

Redis doesn't really provide high-level abstractions like ACID transactions, it provides a set of low-level [commands](https://redis.io/commands) which you can (hopefully) combine to fit your needs. And if you need rollback functionality for a task queue, the main command of interest is [`RPOPLPUSH`](https://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush):

> Atomically returns and removes the last element (tail) of the list stored at `source`, and pushes the element at the first element (head) of the list stored at `destination`.

The docs actually detail a solution to this problem (the "reliable queue"). Basically, you can use `RPOPLPUSH` to (atomically) move items into a secondary "in progress" list, delete them once they're processed, and monitor the list for orphaned items, probably re-enqueueing them after some timeout (or using some other way of detecting dead processors).

If you don't want to go to all this trouble yourself, there are [a million message queue implementations](https://taskqueues.com/) out there, many of them running on top of Redis.